# Is there a difference between “introduction to” and “introduction into”?

Tags: prepositions

“Introduction to” seems to be much more common than “introduction into”, but is the latter an acceptable alternative? If it is, is there some difference in meaning, tone, or connotations? I was inclined into thinking that “into” suggests a deeper introduction, going deep inside the topic, but is it just me?

I mean specifically the use of “introduction” to mean an introductory presentation of a topic, such as in “Introduction to Linguistics”.

Comment: The phrases can mean entirely different things, not in degrees but in a radical way, depending on context. And no, *introduction into* is not further deeper than *introduction to*. See usage examples from literature.

Comment: This question is based on a misconception and lacks background effort.

Answer (score 1):

*Introduction into* is non-standard in Britain and (as far as I know) most of the US when used in a figurative sense (i.e. in the sense of *making acquaintance with*).

Of course, one can introduce one *physical* object into another, or an idea into a conversation or intellectual construct:

> Jorge introduced the stick of the firework into the neck of the milk bottle.
>
> Hegel introduced the notion of a dialectical process into philosophical discourse.

Comment: Yes, quite so. But You can also be given a short three-day introduction into the sex-life of fleas. And that is the usage I think the OP is getting at.

Comment: Regarding "introduction into the sex lives of fleas", I wonder if "introduction into" is commoner in contexts such as arcane knowledge, secret communities, other worlds of learning. While an "introduction to mathematics" has much less of a connotation of induction into a world of secret knowledge. This would have to be settled by usage evidence, though.